# Single Sign On in FF or Chrome creates 502 NGINX Error while IE works

Tags: django, nginx, single-sign-on

I have a Django, NGINX setup that integrates with Single-Sign-On. Recently we had to change domain names, and are using Akamai to spoof the new URL, while the old domain still resolved to our loadbalancer.

SSO attempts to log in are successful in IE but in Chrome or Firefox there is instead a 502 error.

When IE logs in there is a post from oktapreview.com that generates a 302.

When its firefox or Chrome, there are 3 consecutive posts from oktapreview.com that each creates a 502. The first 2 posts have identical timestamps and the 3rd is 3-4 seconds later. For both Firefox and Chrome, upon refreshing the user finds they are actually logged in.

Any advice on what is causing this? Why are there 3 logs of posts from the SSO server? Why would IE (not edge, but IE) work while Chrome and FF fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future seekers here is the resolution:

SSO creates a huge URL string, which first hits the server in its HTTP buffer. My NGINX and uWSGI http buffers were at default levels, around 4kb each. But the Okta SSO was creating URLs that were something like 20KB in their own right. I had to expand the HTTP buffers for both pieces of software to prevent chopping that string into bits. The error message was an unhelpful 500 error, but was resolved with expanded buffers. In short, keep in mind that SSO adds a lot to an HTTP header.